# How do i store multiple images into multiple matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a file of 100+ images which i need to store each image into their individual matrices. Is there any way i can do this instead of hard-coding (as shown below)?

```
Mat src1 = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-00-mod", CV_8UC1);
Mat src2 = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-01-mod", CV_8UC1);
Mat src3 = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-02-mod", CV_8UC1);
Mat src4 = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-03-mod", CV_8UC1);
Mat src5 = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-04-mod", CV_8UC1);
```

I'm using Opencv and C++.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `CV_8UC1` at the end - I think you want `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` or one of its friends.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
vector<Mat> images;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    Mat in = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-0"+i+"-mod", CV_8UC1);
    images.push_back(in);
}
```

beware that reading a lot of images can be very memory consuming.